# Can't Load Drivers In Code Igniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I always get an uncaught exception when I run my application.

I got error like this :

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: UnexpectedValueException

Message: Session: Configured driver 'files' was not found. Aborting.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\simatur\system\libraries\Session\Session.php

Line Number: 233

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\simatur\application\third_party\HMVC\Loader.php
Line: 138
Function: library

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\simatur\application\third_party\HMVC\Loader.php
Line: 115
Function: library

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\simatur\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 23
Function: __construct

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\simatur\index.php
Line: 317
Function: require_once
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this?

This is my autoload.php and config.php :

```
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'authentification', 'rpdb');
$autoload['drivers'] = array();
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'general', 'general_db');
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array(/*"Generalmodel" => "gm"*/);
```

and this :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

I already try everything that I found in the internet, but it always gave me same error like above.

Please anyone help me how to deal with this problem.

Thank you...

Comment: You have not set your session save path try something like `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH .'cache/sessions/';` folder permission 0700

Comment: @user4419336 it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Old But Good [Tutorial HMVC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ&list=PLBEpR3pmwCawDZ6FgNYoyvicEz4HrJPec)

You are using HMVC you have your controllers in the wrong folder you need to make a modules folder. Just the class names and file names need to only have the first letter upper case.

```
application

application > modules > example

application > modules > example > controllers > Welcome.php
```

Then

```
<?php 

class Welcome extends MX_Controller {

   public function index() {
      echo "hello";
   }

}
```

Url Example

```
http://localhost/yourproject/index.php/example/welcome
```

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

You may get a load error you may need this

https://pastebin.com/vNUhJCss

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand, please explain a litle bit more

Answer (score 0):

As you want to load driver you should mention it in `autoload.php`. So change `$autoload['drivers'] = array();` to

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');
```

Also remove `session` from libraries like `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'authentification', 'rpdb');`

Comment: @christ2702 which version of CI are you using

Comment: it's version is 3.1.4

Comment: try to upgrade to 3.1.8. hope it will fix the issue

Comment: how to do that, because the problem happened when I deploy in different server.

Comment: @christ2702 Download https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/archive/3.1.8.zip and replace entire `system` directory